# Sencha Touch 2 cannot read property of undefined (amfphp2)

Tags: extjs, touch, amfphp

I wanted to create a nestedlist with a store and model. 
My store is in a different file, as is my model.js.

Beware I'm using amfPHP => 2 !

When I call my store 'eventStore' as 'store: App.stores.eventStore' i get the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventStore' of undefined**

The code of my store is this:

```
App.stores.eventStore = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
    model: 'Events',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        params: JSON.stringify(
            {serviceName: 'EventService',
            methodName: 'getEvents'}),
        url: 'http://localhost/amfphp/Amfphp/?contentType=application/json',
        reader: {
            type: 'tree',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});
```

Any idea what my mistake is?

(the EventService.php is running correctly, tested it in the gateway browser of amfphp)

thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You try to assign value of the object App.Stores and it is not defined. Maybe that is your namespace? Then define it:

```
Ext.ns("App.stores");
```